# How to convert from IObservable<A> to IObservable<B>

Tags: .net, silverlight, system.reactive

I have a method which returns the interface `IObservable<A>` (in silverlight) and wish to transforms this into another `IObservable<B>`?

So what do I need to put in place of 'CONVERT_SOME_HOW'

```
public IObservable<Bar> Get(IEnumerable<object> @params)
{

    IObservable<Foo> fooObservable = _resources.Get(@params);
    IObservable<Bar> barObservable = CONVERT_SOME_HOW(fooObservable);

    return barObservable;
}
```

Comment: How do you convert a `Foo` into a `Bar`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as you would in LINQ to Objects, use a projection:

```
var observableB = observableA.Select(a => new B(a));
```

(Obviously, adjust according to your conversion.)

That's assuming I understand the question correctly. It's not quite clear what you mean by "when the subscription to the first observer is executed".

Comment: @AWC: Well that's fine - you just need to provide a conversion between `Foo` and `Bar`.

Comment: couldn't see the wood for the trees on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jon has suggested, if you have a conversion from `A` to `B`, then you can use `Select`.

However, there is also the possibility that you have a conversion from `A` to `IObservable<B>`, in that case you can use SelectMany:

```
var observableB = observableA.SelectMany(a => GetObservableB(a));
```